# GWT Table that supports sorting, scrolling and filtering

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I have a project using GWT and it displays data in a table.

I need a Table for GWT that supports:

- sorting by particular column
- scrolling the data, while the header is immobile
- filtering rows for data searched in the table

The project is being created for internal purpose of the company, so I look for a solution that does not require commercial licensing for such uses.

Answer (score 7):

The standard [CellTable](http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#celltable) supports sorting.
(Hopefully more features will come soon.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a table supporting sorting and filtering : http://code.google.com/p/gwt-advanced-table/

Google itself is working on it. Look at this example in the incubator which supports multi-column sorting and fixed header but unfortunately no filtering : http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ScrollTable

Other grids and tables are available in the incubator at this address : http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=Tables

Ext GWT proposes a very nice table, but it is not free (in your case) : http://extjs.com/products/gxt/

Comment: Ok, but this comes with very little documentation and last update was a year ago. Anyway, this can be a solution.

Comment: Last GWT incubator JAR build is from September this year so it's still an active project.

Comment: Ext GWT would be free in the case he has presented as long as he adheres to the GPL license.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [EXT GWT](http://extjs.com/products/gxt/) (not to be confused with GWT EXT), build entirely in Java. You may have the pay for the license though. I do not known if you have to pay if the application is of internal use.

The Grid widget will do exactly want you want.

The rest of their widgets are also quite impressive.

Comment: ExtGwt (also called GXT) is dual licenced under GPLv3 and a commercial licence. I think you can use GPLv3 code internally without any issues. You need to give the source code out to anyone you give the program out to (so if you sell it, customers need the source too) which is fine for internal use.

Answer (score 2):

Just to keep this up to date:
CellTable now supports paging and single column sorting: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable?hl=de

You may want to adapt yout backend request for filtering, as this is usually more performant.

Answer (score 0):

[GWT Ext](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ext/) provides a table that meets these requirements.

It provides a wrapper around the Ext javascript library, so its best to commit to using either only GWT Ext widgets, or GWT widgests.  They can be combined, but sometimes don't play well with each other.

Comment: Ok, but how about licensing? We have tried MyGWT already, but this requires commercial licensing for non-FLOSS projects.