# GWT Table that supports dynamic filtering

Tags: javascript, gwt

This question is similar to [GWT Table that supports sorting, scrolling and filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161686/gwt-table-that-supports-sorting-scrolling-and-filtering)

However I would prefer open source and I am looking for snappy performance. I want a good way to perform dynamic filtering on rows.

SmartGWT's adaptive filter looks interesting. http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_adaptive_filter_featured_category

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Web Toolkit Incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/) has a range of tables to select from:

- [BulkTableRenderers](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=BulkTableRenderers) Bulk rendering of tables(up to 10x faster then normal rendering).
- [Scrolling tables](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=ScrollTable), where the footer and header are fixed.
- [Paging tables](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=PagingScrollTable), where the table can page through arbitrary data sets.
- [Editable tables](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=PagingScrollTable), complete with common cell editors.

From those, [`PagingScrollTable`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/client/PagingScrollTable.html) ([demo](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/demo/com.google.gwt.gen2.demo.scrolltable.PagingScrollTableDemo/PagingScrollTableDemo.html)) seems the best base for creating your own custom solution. To add filtering to it, you'd probably have to tinker with the underlying [`TableModel`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/client/TableModel.html) (or one of it's subclasses, like [`MutableTableModel`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/client/MutableTableModel.html)).