# GWT: How to implement filtering on CellTable?

Tags: java, gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GWT Table that supports dynamic filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500622/gwt-table-that-supports-dynamic-filtering)

I've been searching SO and docs, but no success.

Is there already implemented some sort of mechanism for filtering a GWT (2.3) CellTable? By filtering I mean "show only those data that pass this condition".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented filtering through implementing an AsyncDataProvider that queries the server using a querystring obtained from the current application place.  The AsyncDataProvider updates the table automatically - you tell the AsyncDataProvider to update the table via:

```
addDataDisplay(final HasData<T> display)
```

If you're not familiar with Activities and Places, take a look at:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

For example, a history token for me looks like this:

```
 EntityPlace:Source/q:sourceType_eq=report.
```

The AsyncDataProvider the uses the Place obtained from the history token to query the server.

HTH.

Comment: Hi, it looks like this is some re-querying data sources, not filtering, or am I wrong? Would you mind posting code sample where it is a little more obvious? Thanks

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of filtering :)  My method was filtering data through re-querying data sources.  The only other way I could think of doing it would be to use a ListDataProvider and maniuplate the list returned from dataProvider.getList() - I don't think CellTable provides any methods for filtering itself.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking of something in pseudo-code like: List<Row> filtered = Filter.matches(dataProvider, new Condition<Row>() {.. });

Answer (score 4):

The [Google Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) R09 has the static `Collection2.filter(..)` method. The library had also been extended to work in GWT apps. To filter an instance of  `Collection<MyType>` before feeding it to your CellTable you can write something similar to:

```
List<MyType> filteredList =
   new ArrayList<MyType>(Collections2.filter(unfilteredList,

      new Predicate<MyType>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(MyType listItem) {
                   return (filterCondition) ? true : false;
                }
             }));
```

now `filteredList` can be fed to your CellTable:

```
     myCellTable.setRowCount(filteredList.size(), true);
     myCellTable.setRowData(0, filteredList);
```

To use the library both `guava-r09.jar` and `guava-r09-gwt.jar` need to be added to your GWT project's classpath.