# GWT Cell Table Scroll

Tags: gwt

I am working to include support for filtering in a cell table. I have been looking for options on how to do this on SO,elsewhere, but I am yet to come up with a solution that would enable me to do  dynamic filtering on a column. It would be difficult for me to change the base table ( its a basic cell table ) to one of the more advanced ones (like the ones i saw here [GWT Table that supports dynamic filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500622/gwt-table-that-supports-dynamic-filtering) ). I am using a list data provider and all the operations will be done on the client side. Could someone give me some advice about how to proceed ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is client side (e.g., you use a simple `ListDataProvider`), then it's all about what you render. Given the fact that every `CellWidget` is backed by a `DataProvider` to retrieve the data to display, then I'd say to apply a filter on the backed list, based on some user input. The view will automatically update itself.

If you want to do some other fancy things, like text highlighting, or view manipulation of data, then you need to poke into the cell `render()` method of your columns. Much like what the [old expenses sample](http://io2011.gwt-expenses-sample.appspot.com/Expenses.html) did at the time.

Side note: the `CellTable` you are using is actually the successor of the widgets you linked in your post. So you are more *up to date* than what you think. And that post is quite old, since the incubator project has been deprecated a couple of years ago and almost all its widgets have found place, in some other nature, in GWT iteself.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the link . I will look into things and get back for more help.